# Copyright details doesn't show Organization name

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield, copyright-display

I am creating an exe using InstallShield 2022. Its a C# WPF code. Once the build is created from InstallShield, When I run the exe as administrator, the pop-up which appears, doesn't show Copyright details, like
"**Copyright. XXXX All Rights reserved"**, but it instead show below message

Any help would be appreciated.

[error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VMjW.png)

Things i have already checked in InstallShield:-

- In Release -> setup.exe -> Use Custom version properties is set to Yes
- Properties table has all the required valued, like company name.
- General Information tab has all the correct details.
- Checked from the code perspective

Comment: Can you share the pop-up snapshot?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal, add the snapshot. Ideally, it should, pop-up, copyright details, like

Copyright 2023. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publisher details in UAC prompt are fetched from digital signature using which executable was signed. This has nothing to do with InstallShield.